# How can I stop someone to forward their iCloud e-mail to my Gmail address?

Tags: icloud, gmail

Since early september, I'm receiving all e-mails sent to `firstname.lastname1@icloud.com` in my Gmail inbox `firstname.lastname@gmail.com`.

In both case, first and last names are mines, but I don't own the iCloud one (I own `firstname.lastname@icloud.com` without the "1" though but I don't think that's relevant here). I verified this by trying to reset password for the `firstname.lastname1@icloud.com` iCloud account only to discover that the associated phone number was not mine.

What I think happened here is that my namesake, owner of `firstname.lastname1@cloud.com` must also own a Gmail address similar to mine and has redirected his iCloud address to my Gmail address by mistake.

Is there a way I could contact him or Apple about this ? Of course I could create a Gmail filter to get rid of his e-mails, but I'd rather warn the iCloud address owner about the mistake.

Comment: Did you try sending him an email?

Comment: Well no but it would just arrive in my inbox instead of his...

Comment: I would have assumed that it will arrive in his iCloud inbox, as well as being transferred to yours/

Comment: @CedricH. There is no way of knowing which other redirections the owner of `firstname.lastname1@icloud.com` has set, or whether they ever have a look at their iCloud account (after all, they redirected to a gmail address for a reason). I would just auto-delete them.

Comment: @nohillside Sure, there's no way to know, so trying it is imho the best move.

Comment: Since you’re getting them and most probably reading them, there can be some contact info of the sender, their relations with the person or work address etc. if it is all marketing, that’s unfortunate for you.